# How to shift an array of posenet points?

Tags: javascript, arrays, computer-vision, p5.js

I'm a beginner at using p5.js but I'm currently currently attempting to create a brush sketch like this
[ellipse brush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JMa.gif)

though using computer vision & posenet nose tracking (essentially a nose brush)

The problem is, while it doesn't state any errors, it doesn't work.

This is my code for the ellipse brush without posenet & camera vision

```js
let mousePosition = [];

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(0);
  
//Every frame of animation
  //storing the mouse position in an array
  mousePosition.push({x: mouseX, y: mouseY});
  
  //shift the array so that the older ones deletes itself
  if(mousePosition.length > 100) mousePosition.shift();
  //loop
  for(let i = 0; i < mousePosition.length; i++) {
    //if the variable is less than 50, loop function
    let x = mousePosition[i].x;
    let y = mousePosition[i].y;
    ellipse(x, y, r,r);
    var r = 20
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the one with computer vision & nose tracking w/ posenet

```js
let capture;
let poseNet;
let pose;
let text;
let pg;
let nosePosition = []


function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 700);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.hide();

  pg = createGraphics(width, height);

  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(capture, modelLoaded);
  poseNet.on('pose', gotPoses);
  // background(255)

  // color picker
}

function gotPoses(poses) {

  //console.log(poses);
  if (poses.length > 0) {
  pose = poses[0].pose;
  }
}

function modelLoaded() {
  console.log('poseNet.ready');
}

function draw() {

  translate(width, 0); // move to far corner
  scale(-1.0, 1.0); // flip x-axis backwards
  image(capture, 0, 0, width, width * capture.height /
  capture.width);
  image(pg, 0, 0, width, height);

  if (pose) {
nosePosition.push({x:pose.nose.x ,y: pose.nose.y});
    
 if(nosePosition.length > 100) nosePosition.shift(); {
}
    for(let i = 0; i < nosePosition.length; i++) {
    //if the variable is less than 50, loop function
    let x = nosePosition[i].x;
    let y = nosePosition[i].y;
    pg.ellipse(x, y, i/5,i/5);
      
    var r = 20 //how big the ellipse is
    pg.fill(255)
    

    pg.noStroke();


  }
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second is essentially very similar to the first, as I've only changed the mouseX/Ys into the posenet Nose keypoint.

Any insight/solution would be highly appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shifting properly, but you forgot to clear the `pg` graphic, which is kind of like forgetting to put `background(0)` in your original sketch. So instead of drawing all the ellipses on a blank background, you're drawing them *on top of* the previous frame.

Adding `pg.clear()` anywhere in `draw()` after you display `pg` on the canvas (`image(pg, ...)`) and before you draw the ellipses (`for (...) {... ellipse(nosePosition[i].x...)}`) should do the trick. Here's where I put it:

```
image(pg, 0, 0, width, height);
pg.clear();//HERE
if (pose) {//...
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you!